# Can I remove windows's ctrl+alt+paddot hotkey?

Tags: windows, windows-11

I would like to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>paddot</kbd> (the period key on the numpad) for a keybind in a game I play. Windows interprets that combination the same as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> though, so the game never sees it. I already have a perfectly functional delete key, and I don't need a backup. Is there any way to disable the keypad version of the hotkey, so the combination can be used in applications?

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there any way to disable the keypad version of the hotkey

No.

For security reasons <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> cannot be remapped on Windows. This is to prevent malicious applications taking over the key combination.

See [Secure attention key - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_attention_key).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to disable the keypad version of the hotkey, so the
> combination can be used in applications?

It is always wiser to remap the App you are dealing with instead of Windows.  Think of Microsoft being the owners of the main keystrokes they reserve.

On occasion, Microsoft Power Toys or Auto HotKey can help.

In this case, Ctrl-Alt-Del has always been secured by Microsoft.

[Cannot remap ctrl alt del](https://www.zdnet.com/home-and-office/work-life/how-to-remap-keys-using-keyboard-manager-in-microsofts-powertoys/)

> you can't remap Win+L (locks Windows) or Ctrl+Alt+Del (gives you
> access to Task Manager) as those are reserved shortcuts.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep that in mind if I ever want to remap ctrl+alt+del. Do you have any insight into the key combination I asked about?

Comment: I am not sure about the Dot (.) The main combination is Ctrl Alt Del

Comment: On this laptop, the NumPad periood key is also labeled "DEL", so it would seem the keyboard decoder maps that key in hardware, and it functions as DEL when Crtrl-Alt are preseed, whether or not NumLock is set. Perhaps other keyboards vary.